# jest how to test localStorage like below? jest v27.4.1

Tags: jestjs, local-storage

here are all codes, I had config browser environment, in jest, how to get num = 10 ?

```js
// a.js
let num = 1
if(localStorage.getItem('setNum')){
  num = 10
}
export { num }

// unit.spec.ts
import { num } from './a'
describe('a.js', () => {
  test('num', () => {
    expect(num).toBe(10) // Expected:10  Received:1
  })
})

// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom', // mock browser environment
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to mock `localStorage.getItem()` method and its return value. Note: we need to mock before `import`/`require` the module.
The `testEnvironment` configuration is `jsdom`.

E.g.

`a.ts`:

```
let num = 1;
if (localStorage.getItem('setNum')) {
  num = 10;
}
export { num };
```

`a.test.ts`:

```
describe('71290459', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const localStorageMock = {
      getItem: jest.fn().mockImplementation((key) => {
        if (key === 'setNum') {
          return 'fake data';
        }
        return null;
      }),
    };
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
      value: localStorageMock,
    });

    const { num } = require('./a');
    expect(num).toBe(10);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71290459/a.test.ts
  71290459
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.279 s
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works.  I should mock localStorage first, and then to require a.js